# Why dealloc is not getting called when ARC is on for project but off for a particular file objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

One of my view controllers has ARC turned off but when I navigate to previous view controller then my dealloc method is not getting called.

For push view controller I used

```
Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone *viewController = [[Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone alloc] 
                                                         initWithNibName:@"Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone" 
                                                         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

IssueDataHolder *dataHolder = [m_arrIssueData objectAtIndex:m_nCurrentIssueIndex];

NSLog(@"%d",dataHolder.nIssueID);

[viewController setM_IssueDataHolder:dataHolder];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

and to navigate previous view controller I used

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: please see updated question now?

Comment: something is holding a strong reference to your view controller.

Comment: may in earlier classes ARC is on so while pushViewContrioller we r not releasing pushed view controller object's memory, may be thats why in pushed ViewControllers dealloc is not getting called

Comment: no that is not it. something is holding a strong reference to your view controller.

Comment: Paul is right, that your problem undoubtedly rests in the fact that something is holding a strong reference to your view controller. And the problem is probably not related to ARC v non-ARC. I've seen it with sloppy `NSTimer` code, but lots of things can cause your controller to be retained. You might start by looking for situations where your un-deallocated view controller might be passing a reference to itself (`self`) to other methods. Just post any suspect `Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone viewcontroller's dealloc was not getting called because in a viewcontroller(in which i am pushing Magazine_ArticleViewController_iPhone viewcontroller) i took a delegate with retain property. when i made it @"assign" then dealloc is getting fired.

I completely agree with  @ **Paul de Lange** 's comment.

**changed delegate's retain property to assign**.

Answer (score 1):

For developers who still have problem dealloc not called and cant found out reason: 
According to Paul's answer `[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` can be reason for this problem. 
You have to cancel `[performSelector:]` before pushing new ViewController.

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(Method) object:nil];
```

Comment: Is that only if the sending of the selector has not executed yet?

Comment: I think, yes, if there is a method, which will be executed with selector after some delay and another ViewController pushed before this method it, dealloc is not getting called.